# Projection of $\mathbf{X}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{a}$: $\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{X} = \sum_{j = 1}^d a_j X_j$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, principal-component-analysis

I am currently studying principal component analysis in statistics. PCA uses the "projection of $\mathbf{X}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{a}$":

> $$\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{X} = \sum_{j = 1}^d a_j X_j$$

I know that $\dfrac{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}}{\vert \vert\mathbf{b} \vert \vert} = \vert \vert \mathbf{a} \vert \vert \cos(\theta)$ is the vector $\mathbf{a}$ in the direction of the vector $\mathbf{b}$, but I'm struggling to see how $\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{X} = \sum_{j = 1}^d a_j X_j$ is $\mathbf{X}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{a}$. Analogously to the $\dfrac{\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}}{\vert \vert\mathbf{b} \vert \vert} = \vert \vert \mathbf{a} \vert \vert \cos(\theta)$ case, how is $\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{X} = \sum_{j = 1}^d a_j X_j$ $\mathbf{X}$ in the direction of $\mathbf{a}$?

Comment: Well if $X, a$ are vectors of the same dimension, then $a^T X = a \cdot X $

Comment: @rubikscube09 That's true, but is it the case that $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{a}$ are the same dimension? Like I said, I'm just learning this now, so this isn't clear to me.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure from the context what $a,X$ are in this context.

Comment: @rubikscube09 I wasn't given any further information besides what I posted.

Comment: Is $X$ a matrix? Vector?

Comment: @rubikscube09 The notation suggests that it's a matrix (and I'm confident for PCA it's a matrix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about PCA, $a$ here is a unit vector.

If $x$ is a vector, then  $$\frac{x \cdot a}{\|a\|}=\frac{x\cdot a}{1}=x\cdot a =a^Tx$$